# AsyncStorage time of creation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

So i am storing data in my app using

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

I was just wondering how i would go about storing the time that this item is added? I want to add a feature where it shows how long ago a status was posted.

My question is: What methods are people using to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user submitted a status, use [`Date.now();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) to get the current time. Then save it with *AsyncStorage*. For displaying how long passed from post time, you can use [`timeago.js`](http://timeago.org/) .